# http api is works on emulator but not on physical devices

Tags: android, flutter, api, http, authentication

when login button is pressed it should navigate to next page using api. it works on chrome emulator but when login button is pressed nothing happens in physical device. could there be problem with the codes?.

```
Future<void> login(String email, String password) async {
   Map request = {'email': email, 'password': password, 'device_name': 'dell'};
   try {
     final response =
         await http.post(Uri.parse('http://192.168.1.98:8081/api/login'),
             body: jsonEncode(request),
             headers: {
               "Content-Type": "appliction/json",
             },
             encoding: Encoding.getByName("UTF-8"));
     // ignore: avoid_print
     print(response.statusCode);

     if (response.statusCode == 200) {
       // ignore: unused_local_variable
       var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());
       // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
       Navigator.push(context,
           MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const FrontPage()));
     } else {
       // ignore: use_build_context_synchronously
       ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
           .showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text("Invalid Credentials")));
     }
   } catch (e) {
     // ignore: avoid_print
     print(e.toString());
   }
 }
```

```
 ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        login(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
                        if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          return;
                        } else {
                          return;
                        }
                      },
                      child: const Text("Login"),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add internet permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

also in login method

```
ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        
                        if (_formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
                          login(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
                        } 
                      },
                      child: const Text("Login"),
```

Comment: I've implement it but its not working either.

Comment: do i have to put the code in the main android manifest? I've found it in the debug android manifest.

Comment: Yeah in main manifest

Comment: I tried it but its not working either

Comment: Do you get anything printed on console?

Comment: no just the application finished message

Comment: Do you get status code printed?

Comment: no it just navigate to the next page with valid credentinals is passed

Comment: When invalid ones? What does it show? And why is ignore use build context synchronously added?

Comment: other status code 422 and 404 does not work either. it just navigate to next page and ignore use build context synchronously is added because of linter waring

Comment: it didnt work..